# CodeIgniter: Load view with uri segment after form validation?

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my codeigniter site I have a list of users which an admin can create content for. When creating new content for a user the url is *example.com/content/new/**5***. 5 being the ID of the user that the content is being created for. When I submit the form and `form_validation` fails I reload the view but the problem is that it loses that last segment on the url with the ID number. Is there a way I can reload the view with the errors and also keep that ID in the url?

Here is my code...

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    $this->load->view('create_content', $data); //reload if validation fails        
} else { 
    //prepare data for the database here
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the ideas is to post to the same URL e.g. use `current_url()`

```
<?php echo form_open(current_url()); ?>
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: that totally worked in my case! Problem now is that when validation fails even though I get redirected to link with URI, all errors messages and repopulation is lost. Do you know a way to keep the errors messages and repopulate form? (I'm already using set_value and echo validation_errors)

Comment: the re-population only works if there's a validation rule set for that input tag...I am not sure what you mean by redirection? is it not POSTing the data to the same page?.